# How to access "other side" of ManyToMany relationships in Django/Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I think I'm lacking the right search term for what I'm looking for here.

I've got a model for `BookPage` that accepts multiple authors in a ParentalManyToMany relationship in Wagtail. I'm able to access each of the authors in a template using this code:

```
            {% with author=page.author.all %}
                {% if author %}
                    {% for aut in author %}
                    <div>
                        {{ aut }}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
```

This prints each author associated with a book.

How do I do the reverse, and get all the books written by a particular author, though? I can't seem to find anything about this in the Wagtail docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

When you define a relation such as a ParentalManyToManyField, Django will set up a property on the target model allowing you to query the relation in reverse - by default, this property is named after the other model with `_set` appended, so `bookpage_set` in this case:

```
{% for book in author.bookpage_set.all %}
```

You can specify a different name by providing `related_name` when setting up the ParentalManyToManyField:

```
authors = ParentalManyToManyField(Book, blank=True, related_name='books')  # - allows you to write author.books.all
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've got it working now.